# Sendmail + Qpopper + Dovecot

Tags: sendmail, dovecot, thunderbird

this is our configuration, we used Sendmail, Qpopper POP3 for clients as Outlook/Thunderbird, Dovecot as IMAP for Rouncube/SquirrelMail.

Dovecot is used only for webmails but i want used IMAP for Outlook/Thunderbird but i cant connect to server with Thunderbird to Dovecot-IMAP:

Previous administration ist left and i want migrate to IMAP but i want backup in Qpopper when i ruined something
My question:
It is possible run Qpopper as POP3 and Dovecot IMAP - together ?

When i try connect with `telnet mail.***.sk 143
                         a login "name" "password` 
i see in my logs

```
Apr 16 14:38:48 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<****>, method=PLAIN, rip=193.87.72.148, lip=193.87.72.148, secured
```

so i think it is ok ? why i cant log with thunderbird/outlook

Comment: Why do you say you cannot connect with Thunderbird or Outlook? Do you not see anything in the logs when you try? You can do a telnet to port 143 and get your password accepted, presumably you can also read your mail that way, so anything else is an Outlook/Thunderbird configuration problem.

Comment: I would not recommend mixing Qpopper and Dovecot on the same backend. Dovecot will act as a perfectly correct POP server without any problems.